# How to select matching parentheses in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to select matching parentheses/braces/brackets in Sublime. I don't mean to select the text between them, I mean just them; parentheses. So you can change one type to another without going back and fort. Its like having 2 cursors at the same time on them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`BracketHighlighter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin in Package Control. Among other features for highlighting various types of bracket pairs and tags, it includes:

> - Bracket plugins that can jump between bracket ends, select content, remove brackets and/or content, wrap selections with brackets, swap brackets, swap quotes (handling quote escaping between the main quotes), fold/unfold content between brackets, toggle through tag attribute selection, select both the opening and closing tag name to change both simultaneously, etc.

I've used some of the features of this plugin in the past and I really like it. The author is also very responsive to bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Thanks for that. But that plugin in changing visuals of matched brackets. I need just the functionality above.

Comment: If you have BracketHighlighter installed, you get the ctrl+shift+p commands "BracketHighlighter: Swap Brackets" and "BracketHighlighter: Swap Quotes" for that behavior. Having two cursors would be a little bit tricky, because you would need to have a different input for each cursor.